# Computing a ratio of each column to a lagged version of itself in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Minimal example:

```
df <- data. Frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2022-02-01"), length=12, by="1 month") - 1,
             X1   = 1:12,
             X2   = 21:32,
             X3   = 51:62)
```

I would like to replace `X1` by `X1 / lag(X1) -1`, `X2` by `X2 / lag(X2) - 1` etc. etc. (I am computing returns). Only the date column remains untouched.

I can do this one column at a time using `df$X1 <- df$X1/lag(df$X1) - 1` etc etc, but I have a lot of columns. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: `df %>% mutate(across(-Date, ~.x/lag(.x) - 1))`

Comment: Works beautifully - thank you very much. Out of interest, how would I do this in Base R?

Comment: In base R `cbind(df[1],rbind(NA,df[-1,-1]/df[-nrow(df),-1] -1))`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with('X'), ~ (./lag(.)) - 1))
         Date         X1         X2         X3
1  2022-01-31         NA         NA         NA
2  2022-02-28 1.00000000 0.04761905 0.01960784
3  2022-03-31 0.50000000 0.04545455 0.01923077
4  2022-04-30 0.33333333 0.04347826 0.01886792
5  2022-05-31 0.25000000 0.04166667 0.01851852
6  2022-06-30 0.20000000 0.04000000 0.01818182
7  2022-07-31 0.16666667 0.03846154 0.01785714
8  2022-08-31 0.14285714 0.03703704 0.01754386
9  2022-09-30 0.12500000 0.03571429 0.01724138
10 2022-10-31 0.11111111 0.03448276 0.01694915
11 2022-11-30 0.10000000 0.03333333 0.01666667
12 2022-12-31 0.09090909 0.03225806 0.01639344
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I decided to go with onyambu's solution as it did not constrain the column names, but this is clearly just as good. Also out of interest, how would I do this in Base R (4.2.1 if that helps)